# Why is my jquery .on('change') not working for dynamically changed rows

Tags: jquery

I have add dynamic table row when the value of change the input class='age' changes. However, when the new rows are added my on('change') function at the bottom of my code stops working and longer function when the input class='row' changes for the new set of table rows, I am not sure why this is happening.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var MAX_ROW = 0;
    var age = $("#age").val()
    var table = "<tr><th>Yr. / Age</th><th>Annual Premium<br>(Beginning of Year)</th><th>Benefits<br>(End of Year)</th><th>Time</th><th>Policyholder's Cashflow</th><th>Yield year on year</th><th>Yield to anniversary</th></tr>"
    for (i = 0; i <= 99 - age; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + (i + +age) + "</td>\
                    <td id='annual" + (i) + "'>0</td>\
                    <td id='benefit" + (i) + "'><input class='row' id='row" + i + "' data-row='" + i + "'></td>\
                    <td>" + i + "</td><td id='cashflow" + i + "'>200</td>\
                    <td id='yield" + i + "'>7</td>\
                    <td id='anniversaryyield" + i + "'>53</td></tr>"
    }
    table += "<tr id='total'><td></td><td id='totalpremium'></td><td  id='totalbenefit'></td><td></td><td id='totalnet'></td><td></td><td></td></tr>"
    MAX_ROW = 99 - age;

    $("#info").html(table);

    $("#age").on("change", function () {

        var age = $("#age").val()
        var table = "<tr><th>Yr. / Age</th><th>Annual Premium<br>(Beginning of Year)</th><th>Benefits<br>(End of Year)</th><th>Time</th><th>Policyholder's Cashflow</th><th>Yield for the year</th><th>Yield to anniversary</th></tr>"
        for (j = 0; j <= 99 - age; j++) {
            table += "<tr><td>" + (j + 1) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + (j + +age) + "</td>\
            <td id='annual" + (j) + "'>0</td>\
            <td id='benefit" + (j) + "'><input class='row' id='row" + j + "' data-row='" + j + "'></td>\
            <td>" + j + "</td><td id='cashflow" + j + "'>200</td>\
            <td id='yield" + j + "'>7</td>\
            <td id='anniversaryyield" + j + "'>53</td></tr>"
        }
        table += "<tr id='total'><td></td><td></td><td id='totalpremium'></td><td  id='totalbenefit'></td><td></td><td id='totalnet'></td><td></td></tr>"
        $("#info").html(table);
        MAX_ROW = 99 - age;
    });

...

    $('.row').on("change", function () {
        var t = $(this).data();
        var r = parseInt(t['row']);
        var yield
        var totalbenefit = 0
        console.log('Hello')

        while (r <= MAX_ROW) {
            $("#row" + r).val($(this).val())
            var benefityear = $("#row" + r).val()
            var annualyear = $("#annual" + r).text()
            $("#cashflow" + r).html(benefityear - annualyear)
            totalbenefit += (+benefityear)

            r++;
        }
        $("#totalbenefit").html(totalbenefit);


        var annual = $("#annual").val()
        var term = $("#term").val()
        var r = 0
        var premiumsofar = 0
        var benefitsofar = 0

        while (r < term) {
            $("#annual" + r).html(annual)
            var annualyear = $("#annual" + r).text()
            var benefityear = $("#row" + r).val()
            $("#cashflow" + r).html(benefityear - annualyear)
            premiumsofar += (+annualyear)
            yield = benefityear / premiumsofar
            $("#yield" + r).html((yield * 100).toFixed(2) + "%")
            r++
        }
        var totalpremium = annual * term
        $("#totalpremium").html(totalpremium)
        $("#totalnet").html(totalbenefit - totalpremium)

        while (term <= MAX_ROW) {
            var benefityear = $("#row" + term).val()
            yield = benefityear / totalpremium
            $("#yield" + term).html((yield * 100).toFixed(2) + "%")

            ++term
        }

        var ay = 0
        var premiumsofar = 0

        while (ay <= MAX_ROW) {
            var annualyear = $("#annual" + ay).text()
            var benefityear = $("#row" + ay).val()
            premiumsofar += (+annualyear)
            benefitsofar += (+benefityear)
            anniversaryyield = (+benefitsofar / +premiumsofar)

            $("#anniversaryyield" + ay).html((anniversaryyield * 100).toFixed(2) + "%")
            ay++

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to bind a function to `class='age'`, you should use `.age` instead of `#age`(# is for id). And when you want to bind a function to dynamically rendered elements, you should bind your function to its parent element and give it a selector. I usually use `body` element for this case like below(it's only for convenience, as @Jeto mentioned, the closest non-dynamic parent would be best for performance aspect):

```js
$("body").on("change", ".age", function () {
    var age = $("#age").val()
    var table = "<tr><th>Yr. / Age</th><th>Annual Premium<br>(Beginning of Year)</th><th>Benefits<br>(End of Year)</th><th>Time</th><th>Policyholder's Cashflow</th><th>Yield for the year</th><th>Yield to anniversary</th></tr>"
    for (j = 0; j <= 99 - age; j++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" + (j + 1) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + (j + +age) + "</td>\
            <td id='annual" + (j) + "'>0</td>\
            <td id='benefit" + (j) + "'><input class='row' id='row" + j + "' data-row='" + j + "'></td>\
            <td>" + j + "</td><td id='cashflow" + j + "'>200</td>\
            <td id='yield" + j + "'>7</td>\
            <td id='anniversaryyield" + j + "'>53</td></tr>"
    }
    table += "<tr id='total'><td></td><td></td><td id='totalpremium'></td><td  id='totalbenefit'></td><td></td><td id='totalnet'></td><td></td></tr>"
    $("#info").html(table);
    MAX_ROW = 99 - age;
});
```

Comment: If possible, for performance reasons, you should use the closest (non-dynamic) parent rather than `body`.